# Remove report Header and footer space in subsequent pages

Tags: reporting-services, header, whitespace, footer

I'm facing a little probleme with my ssrs report, here is what I have to do:

I need to make a report that prints on both sides of the paper. The front will be the main report. The back of the paper will be a company disclaimer. It is just a table with simple text, but it takes the whole page. The back will be the same for all printouts.

I tried to make a report and use the PDF files to print this. The front works OK but I couldn't make the back differently than the front.

I wrote a a condition (`=iif(Globals!PageNumber=1,FALSE,TRUE)`) to show and hide the page header and footer and it works fine. However, unfortunately, white space of the report header and footer is present in the subsequent pages. How can I remove this unwanted white space other than first page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you are only displaying the "header" and "footer" on the first page of the report, then you probably don't need to use a header and footer at all. Just add the necessary report items to the report Body and use the PageBreak property of the last item to ensure a page break occurs in the correct place.

Comment: I have dealt with the header space by deleting the header zone and I moved what's in it in a rectangle, but I couldn't do the same thing to the footer, because the body zone is dynamic. So I started to look for a solution that can calculate dynamically the space left in the page and pin the footer content at the bottom of the page. This way, it would'nt be needed to use a footer zone anymore. I found some content talking about this : [link](https://github.com/AdrianNichols/ssrs-non-native-functions)

Comment: an other one here : [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/08785944-923e-445a-b7de-b1062ea97879/absolutely-pagebottom-alignment-on-report-footer-impossible?forum=sqlreportingservices) , it's not well explained, any ideas how can I do it simply ?

Comment: Another option you can consider is not to try and hide the footer on the subsequent page, just to set the Hidden property on the items *within it* based on page number (using the expression from your original post) - that way the footer is always present but the content is "invisible" on the subsequent pages. This should avoid the white space appearing if the entire footer is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

On the second page (the back), right-click on the header and go to Header Properties. There is an option for "Display Header for this page" that you can uncheck.

Comment: In design mode there is only one page ! so if I uncheck the option you mentioned there will not be any footer in my report .

Comment: In that case, what if you put all the header info in a subreport and then hide/display the subreport based on whether or not the page number is odd or even? Then, to avoid the extra blank space, make sure the area that the subreport takes up ON THE MAIN REPORT is very small, with the ability to grow (canGrow property) in the case where it will be displayed.